# Why may happen if boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::cancel() is called while the socket is just sending message to the remote end?

Tags: boost, tcp, boost-asio

As per the [official document](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html), which says that

> basic_stream_socket::cancel causes all outstanding asynchronous connect, send and receive operations to finish immediately.

But it does **not** say where the data which has not been sent out goes?
Must I resend the entire message again?
Or just resend the data which has not been sent out (in this case, how could I know how many bytes have sent and how many have not?)?

And I know that this API will only cancel asynchronous operations that were initiated in the current thread.

Comment: "And I know that this API will only cancel asynchronous operations that were initiated in the current thread." - that seems wrong. What's your source on that?

Comment: @sehe Here, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html.  The third paragraph.

Comment: that's windows specific (which is why I wasn't aware of it). Also [_"When running on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, and later, the CancelIoEx function is always used. This function does not have the problems described above."_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload2.html#:~:text=When%20running,above)

Comment: @sehe No, that's ***not*** what I pay attention to.     "This function causes all outstanding asynchronous connect, send and receive operations to **finish immediately**".  It says that all these operations are finished  immediately, then the question is what about the message which have been partially sent out? What should I do when this occasion happens?

Comment: I understand that part of the question. It's just the claim that I commented about that is usually not valid/applicable. I think the question would be clearer without it.